# NoClassDefFoundError for ClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to consume a soap webservice and included the relative dependency in gradle file as

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
```

along with Jaxb dependencies. This code works absolutely fine in my local and I am able to retrieve the results from the service, but when I deploy this code to Openshift, I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com..abc.xyz.AccountServiceClient]: Factory method 'accountServiceClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager
    at com.discover.card.collections.aprapi.config.WebServiceConfig.httpComponentsMessageSender(WebServiceConfig.java:43) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.discover.card.collections.aprapi.config.WebServiceConfig.accountServiceClient(WebServiceConfig.java:31) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.discover.card.collections.aprapi.config.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79bdd48b.CGLIB$accountServiceClient$1(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
```

I have tried to add the dependency for HttpClient and

```
implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3")
implementation "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-hc:3.4.2"
```

but it is still not working.

Tried searching as well, but didn't see anybody else facing similar scenario where it works fine in local, but throws error while deploying in openshift.

I am using same yaml profile for both local and dev, so that should also not be the issue.

Pls advise what else can I look out for?